# How to query records from serverUrl salesforce (SFDC)

Tags: api, salesforce, sfdc

I have soap url of salesforce (SFDC). I give call to the url (passing username, pwd and token). In response I get serverUrl, sessionId and userId. How do I now query records from serverUrl What parameters do I need to Pass to it while giving a call to serverUrl? Eg:- suppose I want to query Id,Name from Account object

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce offers detailed documentation of the both the REST API and the SOAP API.

See the [`query()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_query.htm) call for the SOAP API and the [Query endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_query.htm#!) for the REST API.

Authentication is also well-documented for [SOAP](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_sessionheader.htm) and [REST](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm).